# iPod Nano without iTunes (Chromebook)

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-nano

My father has an iPod Nano (4th generation I think, though it may be 5th) and runs iTunes on his aging Windows laptop.  He would like to switch to a Chromebook, which would obviously prevent him from running iTunes locally.

Are there alternative (cloud-based) ways of syncing music to an older Nano device, or is a PC with iTunes required to store music and sync this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

iTunes and a USB cable are needed to synch any iPad Nano. The 7th generation Nano has Bluetooth, but that is for playback only. This Wikipedia page on [all the generations of Nanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Nano) will be elucidating.

Answer (score 1):

yes turn your chromebook into developer mode and it should take about 20 min. once that is done open up a new tab and type ctrl+t it will open a terminal type shell and it should open local host after that type ipod/music/download/67  then be sure to copy the url or file to that and then paste it in the terminal have your ipod hooked up to your chromebook and there you have it

Answer (score 0):

No, because the iPod Nano 7th generation, is only for iMac, As Known As, MacBook Pro & MacBook Air, only. If you plug that iPod Shuffle or any iPod Nano, into a Google ChromeBook, the data will be erased immediately.

Comment: No, because if you plug in your iPod Nano 6th generation into a Google ChromeBook Acer 7, it will erase the music data library automatically immediately. The iPod Nano & iPod Shuffle,- is ONLY for the MacBook Pro & MacBook Air!

Answer (score 0):

No, because if you plug in your iPod Nano 6th generation into a Google ChromeBook Acer 7, it will erase the music data library automatically immediately. The iPod Nano & iPod Shuffle,- is ONLY for the MacBook Pro & MacBook Air!